# How do I Loop values from an object and render them out in HTML?

Tags: javascript

Okay, I'm a serious noob and i've been researching all day and can't seem to find the solution. I have an object that contains multiple data that im trying to render out in a loop.

```
            var domainName = 'mywebsite.com'    

            var games = [

                {
                    name: 'name1',
                    url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
                    imgFile: 'img1.jpg'
                },
                
                {
                    name: 'name2',
                    url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
                    imgFile: 'img2.jpg'
                },



            ];
```

How in the world do I use a loop to pull that data to automatically generate

```
<h1>name1</h1>
<a href="url"></a>
<img src="img1" />

<h1>name2</h1>
<a href="url"></a>
<img src="img2" />
```

any help would be appreciated. I know it might be something real simple, I'm just too new to be able to find a lead. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can easily use :

```
 let renderedHtml=games.map(function(item){
       return `<h1>${item.name}</h1><a href="${item.url}"></a><img src="${item.imgFile}"/>`
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vanilla JavaScript, you can use the JavaScript map function to iterate over each objects inside the array.

Also for creating the elements, you can use the createElement() method of JS and you can change the properties of the respective elements and append it to the DOM.

```
games.map((game) => {
  var h2 = document.createElement('H2'); // create <h2> element
  h2.innerHTML = game.name;
  document.body.appendChild(h2); // append to the DOM

  var a = document.createElement('A'); //create <a> element
  a.innerHTML = game.name;
  a.href = game.url
  document.body.appendChild(a);

  var img = document.createElement('img'); //create <img> element
  img.src = game.imgFile;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var domainName = '.mywebsite.com';

var games = [{
    name: 'name1',
    url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
    imgFile: 'img1.jpg'
  },

  {
    name: 'name2',
    url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
    imgFile: 'img2.jpg'
  },

];



for (i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
  document.write(

    '<h1>' + games[i].name + '</h1>' +
    '<a href="' + games[i].url + '"></a>' +
    '<img src="' + games[i].imgFile + '" />'

  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var domainName = 'mywebsite.com'    
var games = [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
        imgFile: 'img1.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'name2',
        url: "https://www" + domainName + "/game.html",
        imgFile: 'img2.jpg'
    },
];

var element = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
games.forEach((v)=>{
    element.innerHTML += `
        <h1>${v.name}</h1>
        <a href="${v.url}">${v.url}</a>
        <img src="${domainName}/${v.img}">`;
});
```